# Reversing the LambertW function!

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function, lambert-w

I have a very puzzling question.
I have a system of coupled non-linear equations:
$$
\begin{aligned}
z_1 = e^{az_1+bz_2} \\
z_2 = e^{cz_1+dz_2}
\end{aligned}
$$
Let's focus on the first equation but everything seems to be the same for the second equation.
One solution to this problem comes from the LambertW function: $ye^y = x \rightarrow y = W(x)$.
Which this problem would result in:
$$
z_1 = -\frac{W(a e^{b z_2})}{a}
$$
Now I'm rewriting the equation like this:
$$
W(ae^{bz_2}) = -\frac{z_1}{a}
$$
And arguing that having an equation like $W(x) = y \rightarrow ye^y = x $.

So I can write
$$
-\frac{z_1}{a} e^{-\frac{z_1}{a}} = ae^{bz_2}
$$
And now I'm rewriting the equation:

$$
z_1 = - a^2 \exp(\frac{z_1}{a} + b z_2) \\
\ln(z_1) = 2\ln(-a)+\frac{z_1}{a} + b z_2
$$

Coming back to the first equation I can take a log and write the equation as follow:
$$
\ln(z_1) = az_1+bz_2
$$
Now I'm using this equality from both equations:

$$
2\ln(-a)+\frac{z_1}{a} + bz_2 = az_1 + bz_2
$$
So eventually I can simplify the equation:
$$
z_1 = \frac{2a}{a^2-1}\ln(-a)
$$
We can do the same thing for the other variable:
$$
z_2 = \frac{2c}{c^2-1}\ln(-c)
$$
The surprising result doesn't depend on the coupling coefficient $b$ and $d$ which is something I don't understand. My first guess is that I'm doing something wrong here. Maybe this step  $W(x) = y \rightarrow ye^y = x $. Can you help me where things go wrong?

Comment: I see the problem in the first two equations where $W$ appears. They are not equivalent, and they have no justification. They look totally unrelated with the initial problem.

Comment: @Crostul This set of equations are coming from diffusion approximation of the non-linear Hawkes process. But the appearance of the W function is trivial and I don't see a problem with it.

Comment: I hope you can see why $$z_1=- \frac{W(ae^{bz_2})}{a}$$ is not the same as $$W(ae^{bz_2}) = -\frac{z_1}{a}$$ Here there is a stupid algebra mistake. A part from this, I don't see how one of these should follow from the origianal problem.

Comment: There's also an algebraic mistake when solving the first equation. It should be $$z_1 = -\frac{1}{a} W\left(\color{red}{-}a e^{b z_2}\right)$$

Comment: @Crostul You are right. If I do it correctly I get back to the first equation which doesn't help me in terms of separation of variables.

Comment: @jjagmath Yes. I noticed it. Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Crostul and @jjagmath mentioned the mistake comes from
$$
-\frac{z_1}{a} = W(-a e^{bz_2})
$$
Which should be
$$-az_1 = W(-ae^{bz_2})$$
And having that we only get back to the main equation after all the calculations.
$$
-az_1 e^{-az_1} = -ae^{bz_2} \rightarrow z_1 = e^{az_1 + bz_2}
$$